# How to disable scrolling programmatically while allowing child scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery/Javascript, I am disabling scrolling within the `body` if a certain element exists.

Although, this also disables scrolling within all other elements on the page.

```
$("body").on('scroll touchmove mousewheel', function(e) {
    if($("#myElem").length > 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
});
```

The reason for me doing it without CSS is because the `md-backdrop` element is controlled by a third-party plugin that I am unable to modify.

How can I only disable scrolling within the body, yet allow scrolling within all my child elements that allow an `overflow` of `scroll` or `auto`?

With the following example, you can see that both the body and red area is scrollable. Once the button is clicked and the `myElem` element is prepended to the page, both the body and red area has disabled scrolling. I require the body to be disabled, although the red area to still be enabled in this case.

**[WORKING EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/pdLuxcsu/)**

Comment: Missing something here? `$("md-backdrop")`

Comment: @Tushar - Sorry, what? Simply using jQuery to reference the `md-backdrop` element (`<md-backdrop></md-backdrop>`) and checking if it exists with `length`.

Comment: @Fizzix I guess that is Angular-material's element which might be replaced by other content. Can you add live demo

Comment: @Tushar - Doesn't have to be `md-backdrop`, can be any element, such as `#myElement` instead. That's kind of irrelevant to the question though. All I am trying to achieve is disabling scrolling on the `body`, yet allow scrolling with all other child elements that allow it.

Comment: I will put together a basic demo now.

Comment: Example link is now within the question.

Comment: Don't see `md-backdrop` element in the fiddle. Can you add exact code.

Comment: @Tushar - I stated that before. The `md-backdrop` is irrelevant to the question. Please see my added notes in the question.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/pdLuxcsu/1/

Comment: @RayonDabre - The problem with reading `e.target` is that I have multiple (around 12+) scrollable children on my page. I would have to give each one a specific ID or class to reference all of these here. There are also other dynamic scrollable elements on the page that would be hard to target this way. Is there a better way to achieve this...?

Comment: @RayonDabre - but as I stated, there are so many other scrollable elements within the page that would need to be referenced, some that do not have classes or IDs since they are created by third party libraries.

Comment: Is this fine: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/pdLuxcsu/2/

Answer (score 0):

Read `e.target` to get the `target` element for `specified-events` and apply conditions accordingly.

```js
$("body").on('scroll touchmove mousewheel', function(e) {
  if ($("#myElem").length > 0 && (e.target.id !== 'myScroller')) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
  }
});

$("#myBtn").on("click", function() {
  if ($("#myElem").length > 0) {
    $("#myElem").remove();
  } else if ($("#myElem").length === 0) {
    $("body").prepend("<div id='myElem'>This element disables all scrolling since it exists</div>");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: green;
}
#myElem {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
#myScroller {
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Click the below button to toggle the element that is appended to the body. While scrolling, it will check if that element exists. If it exists, scrolling on the body and within the read area is disabled. Need the body disabled, although red area enabled.
<br />
<br />
<button id="myBtn">
  Toggle element
</button>

<div id="myScroller">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ut viverra diam. Aenean semper mauris vitae libero tempor, tempus mattis turpis imperdiet. Donec a tellus ut elit commodo convallis. Suspendisse eu egestas magna. Sed turpis dolor, lacinia
  quis orci sit amet, efficitur pulvinar dui. Sed quis metus turpis. Praesent non venenatis sem. Vestibulum tristique sagittis dignissim. In aliquam est vel nunc luctus, vel cursus dolor eleifend. Pellentesque facilisis tempor dui sed viverra. Mauris
  sed viverra libero. Suspendisse nisl mauris, cursus id purus non, iaculis lobortis neque. Duis sed tempor mauris, in dictum lorem. Nunc orci elit, rutrum eu est porttitor, pretium iaculis odio. Aenean eu velit posuere, maximus risus at, egestas mauris.
  Nullam at diam diam. Suspendisse vel dui dignissim, laoreet nibh ut, iaculis elit. Quisque eu convallis dui. Quisque cursus, urna vitae mattis consequat, urna orci consectetur urna, commodo malesuada lacus urna eu nunc. Nunc in nunc at leo molestie
  aliquam. Nunc interdum sollicitudin rutrum. Nam molestie pulvinar ullamcorper. Sed blandit vestibulum porta. Curabitur semper eu ipsum eu commodo. Nunc faucibus ac orci quis ornare. Morbi ornare leo in mi sodales, eget iaculis enim viverra. Nunc at
  ligula tortor. Aenean condimentum a tellus quis congue. Nulla eu hendrerit erat. Donec egestas arcu lacinia mattis mollis. Mauris quis maximus eros. Donec ut risus ultricies, sollicitudin lacus sit amet, aliquet nisi. Aenean pellentesque velit justo,
  a eleifend quam consectetur blandit. Praesent quis magna sit amet nibh luctus congue sed lobortis sem. Sed ut aliquet diam. Vestibulum pharetra ex ac lectus iaculis, eu aliquet erat placerat. Donec rutrum lobortis tellus, eu efficitur nibh vulputate
  eu. Curabitur placerat id quam vel egestas. Proin consectetur sollicitudin lorem. Integer sollicitudin at quam vel sagittis. Integer sed pretium quam, vitae convallis leo. Suspendisse lorem nulla, imperdiet nec cursus id, auctor quis ante. Integer mollis
  vel neque sed commodo. Quisque venenatis nulla quis aliquet porta. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed lobortis euismod est sed sagittis. Ut aliquet a tortor id rhoncus. Sed commodo risus
  cursus, dignissim nulla vel, molestie ipsum. Cras ac ante luctus diam rutrum placerat eu et risus. Pellentesque sed mauris fringilla nulla imperdiet facilisis a eu leo. Vivamus sollicitudin nibh ac augue ultrices, ut bibendum metus viverra. Donec lectus
  urna, lacinia eu bibendum sed, convallis sed ex. Mauris commodo neque sed sollicitudin pharetra. Aenean ac risus ligula. Nunc congue ultrices volutpat. Aenean ac enim porttitor, hendrerit mauris at, ultrices quam. Mauris euismod commodo purus, egestas
  semper metus aliquet ac. Quisque nec consectetur sapien. In vestibulum, urna sed lobortis sagittis, sapien ex interdum nisl, id varius orci dolor sit amet dolor. Nunc quis lobortis velit. Praesent viverra eros at nulla pulvinar accumsan. Nulla interdum
  urna odio, vel ultricies ante fermentum tincidunt. Sed in nibh quam. Phasellus maximus metus diam, ac vulputate enim fermentum ac. Vestibulum bibendum elit justo, at semper risus consequat ut. Pellentesque facilisis mi et vulputate feugiat. Suspendisse
  egestas mauris at elit ullamcorper, non aliquet elit fermentum.
</div>
```

**Edit:** Dealing with `overflow` property of `body` element will also help!

```js
$("#myBtn").on("click", function() {
  $('body').toggleClass('hideIt');
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: green;
}
#myElem {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
#myScroller {
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
body.hideIt {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Click the below button to toggle the element that is appended to the body. While scrolling, it will check if that element exists. If it exists, scrolling on the body and within the read area is disabled. Need the body disabled, although red area enabled.
<br />
<br />
<button id="myBtn">
  Toggle element
</button>

<div id="myScroller">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ut viverra diam. Aenean semper mauris vitae libero tempor, tempus mattis turpis imperdiet. Donec a tellus ut elit commodo convallis. Suspendisse eu egestas magna. Sed turpis dolor, lacinia
  quis orci sit amet, efficitur pulvinar dui. Sed quis metus turpis. Praesent non venenatis sem. Vestibulum tristique sagittis dignissim. In aliquam est vel nunc luctus, vel cursus dolor eleifend. Pellentesque facilisis tempor dui sed viverra. Mauris
  sed viverra libero. Suspendisse nisl mauris, cursus id purus non, iaculis lobortis neque. Duis sed tempor mauris, in dictum lorem. Nunc orci elit, rutrum eu est porttitor, pretium iaculis odio. Aenean eu velit posuere, maximus risus at, egestas mauris.
  Nullam at diam diam. Suspendisse vel dui dignissim, laoreet nibh ut, iaculis elit. Quisque eu convallis dui. Quisque cursus, urna vitae mattis consequat, urna orci consectetur urna, commodo malesuada lacus urna eu nunc. Nunc in nunc at leo molestie
  aliquam. Nunc interdum sollicitudin rutrum. Nam molestie pulvinar ullamcorper. Sed blandit vestibulum porta. Curabitur semper eu ipsum eu commodo. Nunc faucibus ac orci quis ornare. Morbi ornare leo in mi sodales, eget iaculis enim viverra. Nunc at
  ligula tortor. Aenean condimentum a tellus quis congue. Nulla eu hendrerit erat. Donec egestas arcu lacinia mattis mollis. Mauris quis maximus eros. Donec ut risus ultricies, sollicitudin lacus sit amet, aliquet nisi. Aenean pellentesque velit justo,
  a eleifend quam consectetur blandit. Praesent quis magna sit amet nibh luctus congue sed lobortis sem. Sed ut aliquet diam. Vestibulum pharetra ex ac lectus iaculis, eu aliquet erat placerat. Donec rutrum lobortis tellus, eu efficitur nibh vulputate
  eu. Curabitur placerat id quam vel egestas. Proin consectetur sollicitudin lorem. Integer sollicitudin at quam vel sagittis. Integer sed pretium quam, vitae convallis leo. Suspendisse lorem nulla, imperdiet nec cursus id, auctor quis ante. Integer mollis
  vel neque sed commodo. Quisque venenatis nulla quis aliquet porta. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed lobortis euismod est sed sagittis. Ut aliquet a tortor id rhoncus. Sed commodo risus
  cursus, dignissim nulla vel, molestie ipsum. Cras ac ante luctus diam rutrum placerat eu et risus. Pellentesque sed mauris fringilla nulla imperdiet facilisis a eu leo. Vivamus sollicitudin nibh ac augue ultrices, ut bibendum metus viverra. Donec lectus
  urna, lacinia eu bibendum sed, convallis sed ex. Mauris commodo neque sed sollicitudin pharetra. Aenean ac risus ligula. Nunc congue ultrices volutpat. Aenean ac enim porttitor, hendrerit mauris at, ultrices quam. Mauris euismod commodo purus, egestas
  semper metus aliquet ac. Quisque nec consectetur sapien. In vestibulum, urna sed lobortis sagittis, sapien ex interdum nisl, id varius orci dolor sit amet dolor. Nunc quis lobortis velit. Praesent viverra eros at nulla pulvinar accumsan. Nulla interdum
  urna odio, vel ultricies ante fermentum tincidunt. Sed in nibh quam. Phasellus maximus metus diam, ac vulputate enim fermentum ac. Vestibulum bibendum elit justo, at semper risus consequat ut. Pellentesque facilisis mi et vulputate feugiat. Suspendisse
  egestas mauris at elit ullamcorper, non aliquet elit fermentum.
</div>
```

Comment: This would fail if the `myScroller` element has multiple elements inside of it, such as anchor tags, other divs, paragraph tags, and all others since `e.target` would be that specific element, and not `myScroller`.

Comment: Well the provided answer was considering the example you had provided! I did provide other `css` solution in the comments which is not answered yet!

Comment: I was able to fix it with a mixture of both your solutions. The final code was - `if($("#myElem").length > 0) { $("body").css("overflow", "hidden") } else { $("body").css("overflow", "") }`. Therefore, only the body's scroll is being prevented. Yet if the `myElem` does not exist, the overflow hidden is removed.

Comment: I was unsure about your requirement..It is better to manipulate `overflow` rather that dealing with many other conditions.. I'm glad it helped! _Happy Coding_ :)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to set the `scrollTop()` of parent to zero whenever a scroll event on it is detected.

See the working example below.

```js
$(function () {
  //fill up show data
  var str = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    str += i + "\n";
  }
  $(".grandchild pre").text(str);
  console.log("started");
  //fixed scrolling on parent
  $(".parent").on("scroll touchmove mousewheel", function(e) {
    console.log('moved ' + $(this).attr('class'));
 $(this).scrollTop(0);
  }).click(function () {
   alert('clicked');
  });
});
```

```css
.parent, .child, .grandchild {
  padding : 5px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.parent {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 200px;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 400px;
}

.grandchild {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='parent'>
  parent
  <div class='child'>
    child
    <div class='grandchild'>
      grandchild
      <pre></pre>
    </div> 
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the best case for UI. Would confuse the using by scrolling them to the top in many scenarios.

Comment: It's happens too fast, parent will not scroll. At least I'm not able to see the parent move.

Comment: Forgive me if I am wrong, but I think you may have misunderstood the question. Please see my last paragraph within the original question along with the example.

Comment: you mean when the toggle is clicked scrollbar on the body should freeze in it's position while children should be scrollable ?